# Uniform distribution without cycles in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

I need to distribute the count  of orders for users.
Suppose there are 3 orders and 5 users.

```
users    orders
    us1 1
    us2 1
    us3 1
    us4 0
    us5 0
```

11 orders and 5 users

```
users    orders
    us1 2
    us2 2
    us3 2
    us4 2
    us5 3


DECLARE @countInterval int = 13
--DECLARE @sum int = 5
DECLARE @countUser int = 5
        Update DistributionBasesUsers 
            SET  @countUser=@countUser-1, @countInterval=@countInterval-2, DistributionBaseCountOrder=
                CASE 
                    WHEN @countUser>0 THEN FLOOR(@countInterval/@countUser) ELSE 0
                    --WHEN FLOOR(@countInterval/@countUser)<0 THEN @countInterval%5
                    --WHEN FLOOR(@countInterval/@countUser)=0 THEN 0
                END
```

Comment: Are you using MySQL or MS SQL Server? (Don't add unrelated tags.)

Comment: Hang on, what's the logic here? In your first example, it appears that lower numbered users received the "excess" when the number of users didn't exactly divide the number of orders. But in your second example, the reverse seems to be the case.

Comment: Sorry, I using MS SQL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've got something that is similar to what you're asking for. I give different results for your second example than you do, and I'm not sure what the `update` was meant to be doing:

```
declare @t table (users char(3))
insert into @t(users) values
('us1'),
('us2'),
('us3'),
('us4'),
('us5')

declare @orderCount int
set @orderCount = 13

;With CountedNumbered as (
    select
        *,
        COUNT(*) OVER () as Cnt,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY users) as Rn
    from
        @t
)
select
    users,
    (@orderCount / Cnt) +
    CASE WHEN @orderCount % Cnt >= Rn THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as orders
from
    CountedNumbered
```

Results:

```
users orders
----- -----------
us1   3
us2   3
us3   3
us4   2
us5   2
```

---

If we add a nullable `orders int` column to `@t` then we can change the final query to:

```
update CountedNumbered
set orders = 
    (@orderCount / Cnt) +
    CASE WHEN @orderCount % Cnt >= Rn THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

If that was the intent of your `update`. (Doing updates via [CTEs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/with-common-table-expression-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) can be jarring if you've not see it before)

Comment: Nice tip (updating CTE). Another level: you can update table valued - cte based function too :)